# python utc dates and sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

My aim is to data from pandas dataframe and insert into SQL database.  However, I've hit a few problems with time and UTC.  I've broken it down into 3 scenarios, from the code below just uncomment the relevant lines of code marked for each scenario.

scenario 1, convert dates to date/time (non utc) in pandas and then insert into sql and I get the follow error messages:

> "Exception has occurred: ValueError Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot
> be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True   File
> "/home/tbgiot04/OEE_forge/OEE_module/test_sql.py", line 34, in
>
> df.to_sql("test_table", engn, if_exists='replace')"

Scenario 2 with  utc=True i get the following error resulting in the data not being inserted.

> Exception has occurred: ProgrammingError (pyodbc.ProgrammingError)
> ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL
> Server]A table can only have one timestamp column. Because table
> 'test_table' already has one, the column 'end_date' cannot be added.
> (2738) (SQLExecDirectW)") [SQL:  CREATE TABLE test_table (    [index]
> BIGINT NULL,      employee_no BIGINT NULL,    start_date TIMESTAMP NULL,
> end_date TIMESTAMP NULL )
>
> ] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)   File
> "/home/tbgiot04/OEE_forge/OEE_module/test_sql.py", line 37, in
>
> df.to_sql("test_table", engn, if_exists='replace')

Scenario 3, I have the utc = True lines and the dt.tz_localize lines.  pandas/SQL alchemy sends the data but the times are incorrect. The pandas DataFrame and SQL data show the same but don't match the codes in the source.  How can I correctly insert this data into a the SQL database?

```
   employee_no          start_date            end_date
0            1 2019-12-05 15:55:47 2019-12-05 15:55:47
1            2 2021-07-13 21:38:39 2021-07-13 21:38:39
```

.

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


AZUREUID = 'tb-test'                                    # Azure SQL database userid
AZUREPWD = 'test'                                # Azure SQL database password
AZURESRV = 'tb-sql01.database.windows.net'   # Azure SQL database server name (fully qualified)
AZUREDB = 'TB-test'                                      # Azure SQL database name (if it does not exit, pandas will create it)
TABLE = 'DataTable'                                      # Azure SQL database table name
#DRIVER = 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'                 # ODBC Driver
#DRIVER = 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0'                 # ODBC Driver
#DRIVER={/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.0.so.1.1}

   
connectionstring = 'mssql+pyodbc://{uid}:{password}@{server}:1433/{database}?driver={driver}'.format(
    uid=AZUREUID,
    password=AZUREPWD,
    server=AZURESRV,
    database=AZUREDB,
    driver=DRIVER.replace(' ', '+'))

engn = create_engine(connectionstring)

d = {"employee_no" : [1,2], "start_date" : ["2019-12-05 15:55:47 +00:00","2021-07-13 22:38:39 +01:00"] , "end_date" : ["2019-12-05 15:55:47 +00:00","2021-07-13 22:38:39 +01:00"] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df["start_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start_date"]) # senario 1 
df["end_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["end_date"])  # senario 1 

#df["start_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start_date"], utc=True) # senario 2 and 3 
#df["end_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["end_date"], utc=True) # senario 2 and 3 

# df["start_date"] = df["start_date"].dt.tz_localize(None)  # senario 3 
# df["end_date"] = df["end_date"].dt.tz_localize(None) # senario 3 

print(df)
df.to_sql("test_table", engn, if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: SQL Server (and, I suspect, Azure SQL as well) accept [properly-formatted string literals](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Tips-and-Tricks-by-Database-Platform#datetimeoffset-columns-eg-odbc-sql-type--155-is-not-yet-supported) for `datetimeoffset` columns. While it is usually recommended to use "proper" datetime objects for date/time values in this case you might be better off *not* trying to convert the strings, especially since it looks like they are already in the format that T-SQL requires.

Comment: Many thanks for the quick answer,.  If I leave them as objects they import as varchar.  What's the best way to make use of the datetime functionality in SQL.  I have lots of columns with dates, ive just pulled 2 out as a example.

Comment: Is there anyway to convert from utc to uk time within pandas?

Answer (score 0):

> If I leave them as [string] objects they import as varchar.

Yes, that will happen with `if_exists="replace"`. However, we can use `dtype=` to specify the desired column type:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(1, "2021-07-13 22:38:39 +01:00")], columns=["id", "dto"])
df1.to_sql(
    "dto_test",
    engine,
    index=False,
    if_exists="replace",
    dtype={"dto": sqlalchemy.DateTime(timezone=True)},
)
df2 = pd.read_sql_table("dto_test", engine)
print(df2)
"""
   id                       dto
0   1 2021-07-13 21:38:39+00:00
"""
dto_value = df2.iloc[0, 1]
print(type(dto_value))  # <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
print(repr(dto_value))  # Timestamp('2021-07-13 21:38:39+0000', tz='UTC')
```

So it looks like pandas is normalizing the datetimeoffset value to UTC, but at least it is a timezone-aware value.

> Is there anyway to convert from utc to uk time within pandas?

I'm not sure about doing that in pandas itself, but [pytz](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/) seems to be commonly used for that sort of "local date/time" conversion where things can get weird with Standard/Daylight/Summer Time conversions that account for the specific date in question (including changes in the rules by which the time "changes", as happened in the USA as recently as 2007).

Comment: Thanks again, when i run the same code i get "pyodbc.DataError: ('22007', '[22007] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (241) (SQLExecDirectW)')".  I take it yours worked without error?

Comment: Yup, that's a straight copy/paste from my PyCharm code window. FWIW, I'm using pandas 1.3.1, SQLAlchemy 1.4.22, pyodbc 4.0.31, msodbcsql 17.7.2, and hitting a SQL Server 2017 Express instance.